# problems with management of user groups in dspace

Tags: dspace

I have a problem with the user administration, with groups users. I want to add users to a particular group, but I dont have the button "Select Users ..."

[image]

DSpace Version: 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was with the styles, changed a parameter to the buttons will move off the screen.
In my case I made some changes in dspace\webapps\jspui\static\css\Bootstrap\bootstrap.css

I hope have someone else can help.

a greeting